How to remove parts without without having the shape hollowed
I want to remove faces from a part to only keep a part of it. But the side that is left from removing the other part is hollow from one side since It was connected to the other shape. how do I fill it or add a face there after removing those faces?
This is the example I am working with. I am trying to make a bench similar to this image 

Press A to select all in edit mode:

Go to Select > Select Loops > Boundary Loop to get only the outer edges:

Then press F to fill those faces.

